# Bullet List (or similar to) in a Linear View between TextViews

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I try to build a bullet list with ListView and use it in my scrollable LinearLayout but it doesn't expand the list (I have to scroll the ListView).

Here a screenshot: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-15149543/2012-07-16_16-28-42.jpg.html

The Listview is under > Kontraindikation.

I used this example: http://www.technotalkative.com/android-bullets-in-listview/

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wirk_t"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#33B5E5" 
            android:text="@string/notmedi_wirk" />  
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wirk_f"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textStyle="bold"  />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/handel_t"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#33B5E5" 
            android:text="@string/notmedi_handel" 
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/right" /> 
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/handel_f"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:visibility="gone" />    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ind_t"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#33B5E5" 
            android:text="@string/notmedi_ind" 
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/right" /> 
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ind_f"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:visibility="gone" />    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/medi_kontra_t"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#33B5E5" 
            android:text="@string/notmedi_medi_kontra" 
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/right" /> 
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="@null"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/medi_beschr_t"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#33B5E5" 
            android:text="@string/notmedi_medi_kontra" 
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/right" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/medi_beschr_f"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:visibility="gone" />     
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This my item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/itemText"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bullet"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="List Item"/>
```

This my adapter:

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);  
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(  
this, R.layout.medi_notmedi_detail_list_item, medi_kontra_list));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` you need to set the `ListView Height` programmatically. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3495908/1436931) is the good code to calculate/set the height of a `ListView'.

Comment: Ok, I will try. I dont understand why google don't give a simple possibility to make bullet lists....

Comment: The solution dont work for my, because some of my entries are longer than one line